# Getting a entry for one table using the other columns in another table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm kind of struggling with my DB design. Please refer this image for clear understanding. 
[image]

In the tbo_current_status table, there is an active_status field and I want to fill it with any one the fields in tbo_status (status_type_1,status_type_2...etc). How can I do that?

If you have any different ideas feel free to share them :)

Comment: Something certainly is wrong with the database design.  In a table called `tbo_status`, I would expect one row per status.  Generally separate columns to implement an array or list is a big red flag.  Of course, you haven't described what you are trying to do, so the question cannot really be answered.

Comment: The table tbo_status has the type of status for each project like design->tested->prod while another project can have code->review->deploy. So I tried like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be easier to have tbo_status be [Project ID], [Status Type Number], and [Status Display Name] fields, and then have each status be a record. Then you can use the Status Type Number as the foreign key in tbo_current_status. It doesn't explicitly enforce that there are 5 statuses, the way you did by making them columns, but it's easier to reference them in the way you're trying to use them.

If you want to enforce 5 statuses, maybe you make another table, tbo_status_type_list, that defines the 5 numbers, and make that a foreign key for Status Type Number in your tbo_status table.

Comment: Yes I think the first explanation is nice, one quick question consider I have [Status Type Number] (as foreign key) in tbo_current_status as number 1 . is it possible to change that to number 2 [Status Type Number] (that is a different status display name ) in tbo_current_status ?

Comment: I think that is not a problem, as it moves from one status to the next you can update the value of the foreign key for that row.